# $2\times2$ trig matrices with finite order

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

In the group

\begin{bmatrix}\cos x&-\sin x\\ \sin x& \cos x\end{bmatrix}

Are there real values of $x$ other than $0, \pi, 3\pi/2$, and $2\pi$ for which the matrix would be of finite order?

Answer (score 2):

Yes: if $x=\frac{2\pi k}{n}$ for integers $k,n>0$ such that $\frac{k}{n}$ is in lowest terms, then the matrix has order $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  this is a rotation by $x$ radians.  Powers of such a matrix add the rotation angle.  What can $x$ be to guarantee $A^n=I$ where $n$ is your favorite natural number?